# Why 800x1280 emulator can't display an application designed for it properly?

Tags: android, size, screen, emulation

I created a 800x1280 emulator (for galaxy note), and write an application for it.

The prototype UI created by photoshop is 800x1280 , you can see the zoomed out picture:

[image]

It's width is 800px and height is 1280px.

I don't have a 800x1280 device, but I have a 720x1024 one(which is smaller than galaxy note), you can see the real application captured from my android pad:

[image]

But when I deploy it into a 800x1280 emulator, it becomes:

[image]

You can see the left side panel looks smaller and the space is not enough to display those text.

The settings for the 800x1280 avd is:

[image]

But why it looks smaller than a 700x1024 pad?

Comment: You sure that's 1280x800 and not 800x1280?

Comment: Thanks, I should write it as 800x1280:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of the LCD that android system understands is dp (density independent pixels) the formula for calculating the dp is px=dp * (dpi / 160) so if you set the physical dpi of the screen to 160 dpi. One physical pixel is equal to dp and hence your resolution appears correctly. What happened earlier was your LCD density was 320 dpi which means one physical pixel was equal to 2 pd so everything appeared expanded. I hope you understood the reason now. :)

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found if I set the `Abstract LCD density` to `160`, the screen of emulator is correct. I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: The density of the LCD in android is dp density independent pixels the formula for calculating the dp is.